# Ubuntu 17.10 - Mouse acceleration or magnet

Tags: 17.10

I've just updated my laptop from 17.04 to 17.10 and I've seen that mouse pointer has a sort of "magnetism" on buttons, something similiar to an acceleration.

This wasn't present in 17.04

How can I remove this acceleration? Is making me crazy.

What I'm saying is that my touchpad, with Ubuntu 17.10, behave differently than 17.04. in 17.10 when moving pointer near buttons or dock, the pointer makes an acceleration to the button center, like a magnet attracting the pointer.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What do you mean by magnetism?

Comment: What I'm saying is that my touchpad, with Ubuntu 17.10, behave differently than 17.04. in 17.10 when moving pointer near buttons or dock, the pointer makes an acceleration to the button center, like a magnet attracting the pointer.

Comment: Which desktop environment is this? Could you please look through its mouse/touchpad and accessibility settings to check if there's a feature like that enabled?